# Support Vectors of SVM

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

I have read somewhere that the value of slack variables of support vectors is not 0. Does that mean the points lying in the wrong region e.g a positive point lying in the negative region will also be a support vector? I have attached one picture as well which shows that points lying in the wrong region also support vectors. I am looking for an explanation of this phenomenon[image: Total Support vectors are 12 points and one is outside margin is also support vector?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are support vectors. This is because they contribute (or serve as **support**) in the computation of the hyperplane that separates the positive and negative regions. This hyperplane is given by:

$$\mathbf{w}^T x + b = 0 $$

Where $x$ is our $\text{n-dimensional}$ input **vector** that contains the $n$ features of our problem (the input samples during the learning process), and $b$ and $\mathbf{w} = (w_1,w_2,...,w_n)^T$ are the parameters that are optimized. More concretely, $b$ is the intercept of the hyperplane and  $(w_1,w_2,...,w_n)^T$ is its normal vector (justification in [Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html)).

**But why the misclassified points contribute?**

*More detailed justifications can be found in the [Andrew Ng notes about SVM](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf) which I recommend*.

To understand why they contribute, we need to have a look at the cost function, $J$, that is used when the data is not linearly separable, like the case of the question (this cost function is also used to prevent the influence of outliers):
$$J = \frac{1}{2}\Vert \mathbf{w}\Vert^2 + C \sum_{i=1}^m \xi_i$$
$$\text{subject to}\begin{cases}
y^{(i)}(\mathbf{w}^Tx^{(i)}+b)\geq 1-\xi_i, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, i = 1,...,m\\
\xi_i \geq 0
\end{cases}$$
Where $\xi_i$ is the *slack* of the input sample $x_i$, being $\xi_i = 0$ only when the input sample $x_i$ is correctly classified and presents a *functional margin* $\geq1$.

In order to solve this in a efficient way, it can be proved that by applying the Lagrange duality to the problem presented before (minimizing $J$ w.r.t. $\mathbf{w}$ and $b$), we end up with a equivalent problem of maximizing the next function w.r.t. $\alpha$:
$$ \max_{\alpha}\,\,\,\, \sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{i=1}^my^{(i)}y^{(j)}\alpha_i\alpha_jx_ix_j$$
$$\text{subject to}\begin{cases}
0\leq \alpha_i\leq C, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, i = 1,...,m\\
\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_iy^{(i)}=0
\end{cases}$$

Where each $\alpha_i$ is the Lagrange multiplier associated with the input sample $x_i$.

Furthermore, it can be proved that, once we have determined the optimal values of the Lagrange multipliers, the normal vector of the hyperplane can be computed by:
$$ \mathbf{w}=\sum_i^m \alpha_i y^{(i)}x^{(i)}$$

**Now we can see that only the vectors with an associated value of $\alpha_i\neq0$ will contribute to the computation of the hyperplane**. This vectors are support vectors.

Now the question is: When $\alpha_i \neq 0$?

As explained in the notes linked above, the values of $\alpha_i \neq 0$ are derived from the *KKT conditions* which are needed to be satisfied in order to find the values of $\alpha_i$ that minimize our cost function. These are:

1. $\alpha_i = 0 \implies y^{(i)}(\mathbf{w}^Tx^{(i)}+b)\geq 1$
2. $\alpha_i = C \implies y^{(i)}(\mathbf{w}^Tx^{(i)}+b)\leq 1$
3. $0<\alpha_i < C \implies y^{(i)}(\mathbf{w}^Tx^{(i)}+b)= 1$

**So, in conclusion** the vectors (samples) that lie on the margins (condition number 3 and condition number 2 when $=1$), the vectors that are correctly classified but lie between the margins and the hyperplane (condition number 2 when $<1$) **and the vectors that are misclassified** (also condition number 2 when $<1$) are the ones with $\alpha_i \neq0$ and therefore contribute to the computation of the hyperplane $\rightarrow$ they are **support vectors**.